# $H$ is normal whenever $Ha\not = Hb \implies aH\not =bH$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Topics in Algebra- Hernstein pg-47,Q.9
>
> If $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$  such that $Ha \not=Hb$ implies that $aH\not=bH$. Then how can I show that $gHg^{-1}\subset H$  $\forall$ $g\in G$?

This is what I have done:

For any $h\in H$,$(ghg^{-1})(gh^{-1}g^{-1})=e$ where $e$ is the identity element of the group $G$.

And for $h,k\in H$, $(ghg^{-1})(gkg^{-1})=g(hk)g^{-1}$ which is in $gHg^{-1}$ as $hk\in H$.
Thus $gHg^{-1}$ is a group.

Comment: Hint: by contraposition, the hypothesis on $H$ is equivalent to $aH = bH \Rightarrow Ha = Hb$. This in turn is equivalent to $b^{-1}a \in H \Rightarrow ba^{-1} \in H$. Now pick the right choice of $b$ and $a$ to show that $h \in H \Rightarrow ghg^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: It looks like I brushed this approach aside.How weird of me .Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @user29743 hint, let   $a = bh$.  Then $h = b^{-1}a \in H$ means $ba^{-1} = bh^{-1}b^{-1} \in H$, and since $H$ is a subgroup, $(bh^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1} = bhb^{-1} \in H$. Replacing $b$ as $g$ we have: $ ghg^{-1} \in H$.

It's actually the case that $gHg^{-1} = H$ for every $g$, since if $gHg^{-1} \subset H$, by letting $y = g^{-1}$, we get $yHy^{-1} \subset H \subset y^{-1}Hy =gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: This proof assumes that any element $h \in H$ can be written of the form $h=b^{-1}a$. Can you always do this?

Comment: I am assuming that the proof takes that $ b \in aH$  then it follows that $aH=bH$ and $a=bh$

Comment: I don't get the 'letting y...' step

Comment: A discussion of this answer starts [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60685890#60685890).

Answer (score 2):

By the assumption, $aH = bH$ implies $Ha = Hb$.

Conversly suppose $Ha = Hb$.
Then $a^{-1}H = b^{-1}H$.
Hence $Ha^{-1} = Hb^{-1}$ by the assumption.
Hence $aH = bH$.

Now suppose $b \in aH$.
Then $aH = bH$.
Hence $Ha = Hb$ by the assumption.
Hence $b \in Ha$.
Hence $aH \subset Ha$.

Conversely suppose $b \in Ha$.
Then $Ha = Hb$.
Hence $aH = bH$ by the above.
Hence $b \in aH$.
Hence $Ha \subset aH$.

Therefore $Ha = aH$.
Hence $aHa^{-1} = H$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks.I looked up your profile.Did you actually work as a worker once? In that case it is amazing.

Comment: ["Left cosets are either disjoint or equal, so either $aH \cap bH = \emptyset$ or $aH = bH$. Since $b \in aH\cap bH$, $aH\cap bH \neq \emptyset$. Thus, $aH = bH$."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555909/prove-that-if-b-in-ah-then-ah-bh)

Comment: Or, "Say, $b \in aH$. Then $b = ah'$ for some $h' \in H$.
Now $bH = {bh: h \in H} = {ah'h : h \in H} = { ah_1:  h_1\in H } = aH$"

Answer (score 1):

The existing proofs are actually unnecessarily complicated. There is no need for non-constructive (e.g. by contrapositive/contradiction) proofs, nor any equivalences, nor so many inversions...

For every $g∈G$ and $h∈H$, we have $ghH = gH$ and so $Hgh = Hg$, and hence $ghg^{-1} ∈ Hghg^{-1}$ $= Hgg^{-1} = H$. Therefore $G ◁ H$.

Tada done in one single line...

Comment: The engligthened one. One question tho how did you jump to ghg^-1 is in Hghg^-1

Comment: @Buraian: $ghg^{-1} = 1ghg^{-1}$ and $1 ∈ H$, right?

Comment: The 'hence' threw me off. I thought jt was implied from previous claims when what you said is true by defailt

Comment: @Buraian: Ah I see. The "hence" is for the "$Hghg^{-1} = Hgg^{-1}$", but I presume you figured that out already.

Answer (score 0):

$Ha\neq Hb  \Rightarrow aH \neq bH$ is equivalent to  $aH=bH \Rightarrow Ha=Hb$. This means $b^{−1}a \in  H$ implies $ba^{−1} \in H$. Now let  h∈ H and g ∈ G. Take $b^{-1}= g^{-1}$ and $a = gh$. Then $h = g^{-1}gh = b^{−1}a \in H$. Then  $ba^{−1}\in H$ (given). Since $  (ab^{-1})^{-1} = ba^{−1}$, $(ab^{-1})^{-1} \in  H$, for $H$ is a subgroup. Then $(ghg^{-1})^{-1} = gh^{-1}g^{-1}\in H \Rightarrow (gh^{-1}g^{-1})^{-1} \in H \Rightarrow ghg^{-1} \in H, ~\forall ~g \in G$ and $\forall ~ h \in H$. Therefore $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$, $\forall ~ g \in G$.