# Normal Subgroup Problem

Tags: group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$gHg^{-1}\subset H$ whenever $Ha\not = Hb$ implies $aH\not =bH$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181928/ghg-1-subset-h-whenever-ha-not-hb-implies-ah-not-bh)

Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that whenever $H\circ a\neq H\circ b $ then $ a\circ H\neq b\circ H$.
Prove that $ g\circ H\circ g^{-1} \subset H$, $\forall g \in G$.

Comment: i have proved by contrapositive of given statement i.e
if $aH = bH$ then $ Ha = Hb$. But i want some other point of view. please help in this.

Comment: $aH=bH$ iff $a^{-1}b\in H$

Comment: @WhiteDwarf: I am not sure that I understand what it is that you have already proved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g \in G$.
Suppose $x \in gH$.
Then $gH = xH$.
By the assumption, $Hg = Hx$.
Hence $x \in Hg$.
Hence $gH \subset Hg$.
Hence $gHg^{-1} \subset H$.