# Prove that if $b \in aH$, then $aH = bH$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Let $a$, $b \in G$.

Prove that if $b \in aH$, then $aH = bH$.

Note: $aH$ is a left coset, i.e., $aH :=$ {$ah\in G:h\in H$}.

Comment: Do you know about equivalence relations and partitions and how cosets are equivalence classes? Or maybe just try $aH \subseteq bH$ and $bH \subseteq aH$.

Comment: Just curious...is this a legit proof from first principles, I feel like I must have made a mistake?                                          Assume $b \in aH$ and $aH \neq bH$ then there exists some $x \in aH$ such that $x \notin bH$ but if $x \in aH$ $x = ah_1 $ for some $h_1 \in H$ and similarly $b = ah_2$. Now consider 
$xh_1^{-1} = ah_1h_1^{-1}= a  $ so $b = xh_1^{-1}h_2$  so $bh_2^{-1} = xh_1^{-1}h_2h_2^{-1} =xh_1^{-1} $  finally multiple by $h_1$ so $bh_2^{-1}h_1 = x$ which is a conraditction of $x \notin bH$

Answer (score 4):

Left cosets are either disjoint or equal, so either $aH \cap bH = \emptyset$ or $aH = bH$. Since $b \in aH\cap bH$, $aH\cap bH \neq \emptyset$. Thus, $aH = bH$.